# What can be the cause for difference in MAE outcome from deep-learing with R between these datasets?

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I’m trying to replicate the deep learning example below with the same Boston housing dataset from another source.

https://jjallaire.github.io/deep--with-r-notebooks/notebooks/3.6-predicting-house-prices.nb.html

Originally the data source is:

```
library(keras) dataset <- dataset_boston_housing()
```

Alternatively I try to use:

```
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
```

The difference between the datasets are:

1. the dataset from mlbench contains column names.
2. the dataset from keras is already split between test and train.
3. the set from keras is organised with lists containing matrices while the dataset from mlbench is a dataframe
4. the fourth column contains a categorical variable "chas" which could not be preprocessed from the mlbench dataset while it can be preprocessed from the keras dataset. To compare apples with apples I have deleted this column from both datasets.

In order to compare both datasets I have merged the train and testset from keras into 1 dataset. After this I have compared the merged dataset from keras with mlbench with summary() and these are identical for every feature (min, max, median, mean).

Since the dataset from keras is already split between test and train (80-20), I can only use one training set for the deep learning proces. This training set gives a validation_mae of around 2.5. See this graph:

[image]

If I partition the data from mlbench at 0.8 to construct a training set of similar size, run the deep learing code and do this several times, I never reach a validation_mae of around 2.5. The range is between 4 and 6. An example of the output is this graph:

[image]

Does someone know what can be the cause for this difference?

Code with dataset from keras:

```r
library(keras)
dataset <- dataset_boston_housing()

c(c(train_data, train_targets), c(test_data, test_targets)) %<-% dataset

train_data <- train_data[,-4]
test_data <- test_data[,-4]

mean <- apply(train_data, 2, mean)
std <- apply(train_data, 2, sd)
train_data <- scale(train_data, center = mean, scale = std)
test_data <- scale(test_data, center = mean, scale = std)

# After this line the code is the same for both  code examples.
# ========================================= 

# Because we will need to instantiate the same model multiple times,
# we use a function to construct it.
build_model <- function() {
  model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu", 
                input_shape = dim(train_data)[[2]]) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 1) 

  model %>% compile(
    optimizer = "rmsprop", 
    loss = "mse", 
    metrics = c("mae")
  )
}

  k <- 4
indices <- sample(1:nrow(train_data))
folds <- cut(1:length(indices), breaks = k, labels = FALSE) 
num_epochs <- 100
all_scores <- c()
for (i in 1:k) {
  cat("processing fold #", i, "\n")
  # Prepare the validation data: data from partition # k
  val_indices <- which(folds == i, arr.ind = TRUE) 
  val_data <- train_data[val_indices,]
  val_targets <- train_targets[val_indices]

  # Prepare the training data: data from all other partitions
  partial_train_data <- train_data[-val_indices,]
  partial_train_targets <- train_targets[-val_indices]

  # Build the Keras model (already compiled)
  model <- build_model()

  # Train the model (in silent mode, verbose=0)
  model %>% fit(partial_train_data, partial_train_targets,
                epochs = num_epochs, batch_size = 1, verbose = 0)

  # Evaluate the model on the validation data
  results <- model %>% evaluate(val_data, val_targets, verbose = 0)
  all_scores <- c(all_scores, results$mean_absolute_error)
}  
all_scores
mean(all_scores)

  # Some memory clean-up
  k_clear_session()
num_epochs <- 500
all_mae_histories <- NULL
for (i in 1:k) {
  cat("processing fold #", i, "\n")

  # Prepare the validation data: data from partition # k
  val_indices <- which(folds == i, arr.ind = TRUE)
  val_data <- train_data[val_indices,]
  val_targets <- train_targets[val_indices]

  # Prepare the training data: data from all other partitions
  partial_train_data <- train_data[-val_indices,]
  partial_train_targets <- train_targets[-val_indices]

  # Build the Keras model (already compiled)
  model <- build_model()

  # Train the model (in silent mode, verbose=0)
  history <- model %>% fit(
    partial_train_data, partial_train_targets,
    validation_data = list(val_data, val_targets),
    epochs = num_epochs, batch_size = 1, verbose = 1
  )
  mae_history <- history$metrics$val_mean_absolute_error
  all_mae_histories <- rbind(all_mae_histories, mae_history)
}


  average_mae_history <- data.frame(
    epoch = seq(1:ncol(all_mae_histories)),
    validation_mae = apply(all_mae_histories, 2, mean)
  )


  library(ggplot2)
ggplot(average_mae_history, aes(x = epoch, y = validation_mae)) + geom_line()
```

Code with dataset from mlbench (after the line with "=====", the code is the same as in the code above:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(mlbench)
library(groupdata2)

data(BostonHousing)

parts <- partition(BostonHousing, p = 0.2)
test_data <- parts[[1]]
train_data <- parts[[2]]


train_targets <- train_data$medv
test_targets <- test_data$medv

train_data$medv <- NULL
test_data$medv <- NULL


train_data$chas <- NULL
test_data$chas <- NULL

mean <- apply(train_data, 2, mean)
std <- apply(train_data, 2, sd)
train_data <- scale(train_data, center = mean, scale = std)
test_data <- scale(test_data, center = mean, scale = std)

library(keras)

# After this line the code is the same for both  code examples.
# ========================================= 

build_model <- function() {
  model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu", 
                input_shape = dim(train_data)[[2]]) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 1) 

  model %>% compile(
    optimizer = "rmsprop", 
    loss = "mse", 
    metrics = c("mae")
  )
}

  k <- 4
indices <- sample(1:nrow(train_data))
folds <- cut(1:length(indices), breaks = k, labels = FALSE) 
num_epochs <- 100
all_scores <- c()
for (i in 1:k) {
  cat("processing fold #", i, "\n")
  # Prepare the validation data: data from partition # k
  val_indices <- which(folds == i, arr.ind = TRUE) 
  val_data <- train_data[val_indices,]
  val_targets <- train_targets[val_indices]

  # Prepare the training data: data from all other partitions
  partial_train_data <- train_data[-val_indices,]
  partial_train_targets <- train_targets[-val_indices]

  # Build the Keras model (already compiled)
  model <- build_model()

  # Train the model (in silent mode, verbose=0)
  model %>% fit(partial_train_data, partial_train_targets,
                epochs = num_epochs, batch_size = 1, verbose = 0)

  # Evaluate the model on the validation data
  results <- model %>% evaluate(val_data, val_targets, verbose = 0)
  all_scores <- c(all_scores, results$mean_absolute_error)
}  
all_scores
mean(all_scores)

  # Some memory clean-up
  k_clear_session()
num_epochs <- 500
all_mae_histories <- NULL
for (i in 1:k) {
  cat("processing fold #", i, "\n")

  # Prepare the validation data: data from partition # k
  val_indices <- which(folds == i, arr.ind = TRUE)
  val_data <- train_data[val_indices,]
  val_targets <- train_targets[val_indices]

  # Prepare the training data: data from all other partitions
  partial_train_data <- train_data[-val_indices,]
  partial_train_targets <- train_targets[-val_indices]

  # Build the Keras model (already compiled)
  model <- build_model()

  # Train the model (in silent mode, verbose=0)
  history <- model %>% fit(
    partial_train_data, partial_train_targets,
    validation_data = list(val_data, val_targets),
    epochs = num_epochs, batch_size = 1, verbose = 1
  )
  mae_history <- history$metrics$val_mean_absolute_error
  all_mae_histories <- rbind(all_mae_histories, mae_history)
}


  average_mae_history <- data.frame(
    epoch = seq(1:ncol(all_mae_histories)),
    validation_mae = apply(all_mae_histories, 2, mean)
  )


  library(ggplot2)
ggplot(average_mae_history, aes(x = epoch, y = validation_mae)) + geom_line()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

writing here because I can't comment...
I checked the mlbench dataset [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/mlbench/man/BostonHousing.html) and it said, that it contains the 14 columns of the original boston data set and 5 additional columns. Not sure if you might have a faulty dataset because you state that there are no differences in the column counts of the datasets.

Another guess might be, that the second example graph is from a model which is stuck in a local minima. To get more comparable models, you might want to work with the same seeds to make sure that the inizialisations of the weights etc. are the same to get the same results.

Hope this helps and feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. I used the dataset with 14 columns since this dataset is identical to the Keras dataset.

Comment: The keras dataset is already split in test and train after downloading. I cannot replicate this exact split with the mlbench dataset. For that reason I intentionally had re-run the code with the mlbench dataset several times _without_ the same seeds although it never reaches the MAE 2.5 from the keras dataset.

Comment: So you have a really small sample size...have you already compared the summary() for every feature of the trainsets of mlbench and keras dataset?
Because your code seems to be fine.

Comment: Yes see my text above. They are 100% identical. I can imagine the outcomes are volatile due to the small sample size, although it is strange that I never reach the 2.5 and remain between 4 and 6. So I am wondering if Keras treats both datasets different due to dataframe vs matrix or something like that.

Comment: I also added column headers to the keras dataset (similar to the mlbench dataset) although this makes no difference.